# remove specific char from string depending on the selected dropdown value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove a specific char from a string depending on the selected val of a dropdown.

What I'm trying to achieve is basically, only if #lang.val() == en, remove the first comma in the addr string.

Here is what I have so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mainaddress').change(function() {
    var addr = $(this).find('option:selected').data('addr');
    if ($('#lang').val() == 'fr') {
      $('#theaddress').text(addr);
    } else if ($('#lang').val() == 'en') {
      addr.replace(new RegExp(","), '');
      $('#theaddress').text(addr);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <select id="lang">
        <option disabled="1" selected="selected" class="succtext">language</option>
        <option value="en">english</option>
        <option value="fr">french</option>
      </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select id="mainaddress">
        <option disabled="1" selected="selected">City</option>
        <option value="" data-addr="11, abc, 90210">New York</option>
        <option value="" data-addr="22, qwe, 57937">Toronto</option>
        <option value="" data-addr="33, asd, 59384">Tokyo</option>
      </select>
</p>
<p>
  <span id="theaddress">-----</span>
</p>
```

What if the lang is selected after the addr? What's the easiest way to handle this?

Comment: try my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this. It will handle situation where he select language after addr selected.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#lang").change(function(){
     $('#mainaddress').trigger("change")
   })
   
   $('#mainaddress').change(function() {
     var addr = $(this).find('option:selected').data('addr');
     if(addr==undefined){
       // do nothing
     }
     else if ($('#lang').val() == 'fr') {
       $('#theaddress').text(addr);
       console.log('FRENCH!');
     } else if ($('#lang').val() == 'en') {
       new_text = addr.replace(/,/, '');
       $('#theaddress').text(new_text);
       console.log('ENGLISH!');
     }
   })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <select id="lang">
    <option disabled="1" selected="selected" class="succtext">language</option>
    <option value="en">english</option>
    <option value="fr">french</option>
    <option value="fr">spanish</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select id="mainaddress">
    <option disabled="1" selected="selected">City</option>
    <option value="" data-addr="11, abc, 90210">New York</option>
    <option value="" data-addr="22, qwe, 57937">Toronto</option>
    <option value="" data-addr="33, asd, 59384">Tokyo</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <span id="theaddress">xxxxxxxxxx</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if there is more than one comma in the string then replace the comma in the string with an empty character:

```
  if (addr.match(/,.*,/)) { // Check if there are 2 commas
    addr = addr.replace(',', ''); // Remove the first one
  }
```

If you want to replace all commas in the string use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with the `g` flag:

```
addr = addr.replace(/,/g , '');
```

---

### Example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mainaddress').change(function() {
    var addr = $(this).find('option:selected').data('addr');
    if ($('#lang').val() == 'fr') {
      $('#theaddress').text(addr);
    } else if ($('#lang').val() == 'en') {
      if (addr.match(/,.*,/)) { // Check if there are 2 commas
        addr = addr.replace(',', ''); // Remove the first one
        
        //To replace all commas
        //addr = addr.replace(/,/g , '');
      }
      $('#theaddress').text(addr);
    }
  })
});

 $(".subSelect").change(function(){
   $('#mainaddress').trigger("change")
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <select id="lang" class="subSelect">
        <option disabled="1" selected="selected" class="succtext">language</option>
        <option value="en">english</option>
        <option value="fr">french</option>
      </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select id="mainaddress">
        <option disabled="1" selected="selected">City</option>
        <option value="" data-addr="11, abc, 90210">New York</option>
        <option value="" data-addr="22, qwe, 57937">Toronto</option>
        <option value="" data-addr="33, asd, 59384">Tokyo</option>
      </select>
</p>
<p>
  <span id="theaddress">-----</span>
</p>
```

To handle your issue with selecting address before language you can bind all future events to the `.subSelect` class selector. This means that if you add other select items they all trigger the change event for `#mainaddress`.

Comment: Then you can use a regular expression with the `g` flag to replace all of them: `addr.replace(/,/g , ''));`

Comment: ok, I'm trying to remove the first comma regardless of the amount of them on the string.